# setState | componentDidMount not updating correctly - react-views

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, jsx

I am having a lot of trouble with componentDidMount() and setState. from what I can tell setState is updating since I am able to print the results within my getData function, but I am not able to print it in the render, or componentDidMount(). I think the issue might be that it is rendering before the state is updated or componentDidMount is not triggering correctly. I have been stuck on this problem forever now and I can't seem to figure it out.

I am using express-react-views to render on the server side.

```
const React = require ('react');
const Head = require ('../components/Head.jsx');
const Nav = require ('../components/Nav.jsx');
const Footer = require ('../components/Footer.jsx');
const getPipeLine = require('../../service/Contructor.js');

class ActiveLoans extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
        this.state = { 
        FinalData: {} 
        }; 
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this)
}; 

async getData (){
    try{ 
        let display = new getPipeLine;
        const data = display.then((FinalData) => {
            this.setState({FinalData},  
            (async ()=> {console.log('state set', FinalData)})()) //returns correct results
        }, 1000);
        
        return data

} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
}}

async componentDidMount() {
    try{
    await this.getData(FinalData);
    (async ()=> {console.log('mount', await this.getData())})() //returns nothing
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err.message)
    }
    
}

render(){
    (async ()=> {console.log('Render', await this.getData())})() //returns undefined
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
                <Head />
                <Nav />
                {Array.isArray(this.getData) && this.getData?.map((results) => (
                    <div key = {results.a.LoanNumber} >
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Loan Number</th>
                                    <th>Loan Status</th>
                                    <th>Loan Type</th>
                                    <th>Submit Date</th>
                                    <th>Last Review</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{results.a.LoanNumber}</td> //displays nothing
                                    <td>{results.a.LoanStatus}</td> 
                                    <td>{results.a.LoanType}</td>
                                    <td>{results.a.SubmitDate}</td>
                                    <td>{results.a.LastReview}</td> 
                                </tr>                
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                ))
            } 
                <Footer />    
        </React.Fragment>
)}}

module.exports = ActiveLoans;
```

this is the first few results that I am trying to display

```
a: {
    '0': {
      LoanNumber: 12345252,      
      LoanStatus: 'Initial',     
      LoanType: 'FHA',
      SubmitDate: '1/14/2022',   
      LastReview: null
    },
    '1': {
      LoanNumber: 12345626,      
      LoanStatus: 'Initial',     
      LoanType: 'VA',
      SubmitDate: '1/14/2022',   
      LastReview: null
    },
    '2': {
      LoanNumber: 12345670,      
      LoanStatus: 'Initial',     
      LoanType: 'Conventional',  
      SubmitDate: '1/14/2022',   
      LastReview: null
```

Comment: `this.getData` is a function. Shouldn't `this.getData?.map` be `this.state.FinalData?.map`?

Comment: I've tried that before and I just tried it again. You might be right but I still don't get any results on my page. Right now my main focus is to figure out why I'm not able to print the results of setState inside the render. I think that is the main issue why this isn't working. My best guess is that setState isn't updating before the render.